# Simple Entailment with Excercise

Tags: rdf

I found these excercises with solutions, but I do not understand
this solution. Can you explain me the Simple Entailment to understand this example:
http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~valli/Comp318/PDF/Entailment.pdf

Given the RDF graph G (expressed in Turtle):

```
    :u rdfs:subClassOf :v .
    :u rdfs:domain _:n .
    :w rdf:type owl:class .
    :w :a :x .
```

Is the following graph simple-entailed by G? Explain the answer

```
    :u rdfs:domain _:m .
    :w :a :x .
```

**Simple Entailment Deduction Rules:**

se1:

```
    u a x   .
    ---------
    u a _:n .
```

se2:

```
    u a x   .
    ---------
    _:n a x .
```

**Here is the solution:**

By applying se1 to the triple

```
  :u rdfs:domain _:n .
```

we obtain the following graph:

```
   :u rdfs:subClassOf :v .
   :u rdfs:domain _:n .
   :w rdf:type owl:class .
   :w :a :x .
   :u rdfs:domain _:m .
```

Therefore the graph S

```
  :u rdfs:domain _:m .
  :w :a :x .
```

is entailed by G because S ⊆ G

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand about the solution?  There's really just one step to it, viz., applying se1 to the triple `:u rdfs:domain _:n` to obtain `:u rdfs:domain _:m`.  Can you clarify what doesn't make sense?

Comment: What is the connection between :w and :u? How can we apply the se1 to the triple :u rdfs:domain _:n .? 
Why do we get one graph (:u rdfs:subClassOf :v .   :u rdfs:domain _:n . :w rdf:type owl:class .   :w :a :x .   :u rdfs:domain _:m .)
for me here at least 2 different graphs one for ":u" and one for ":w"?

Comment: Those aren't `:w` and `:u`, which would be absolute IRIs (since the `:` prefix is defined).  Those are _blank nodes_, and act as existential variables.  You might find another StackOverflow question, [RDF Graph Entailment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16561033/1281433), useful here.

Comment: Knowing that `_:foo` is a blank node might make those se1 and se2 rules clearer.  Se1 says that whenever you have a triple `subject predicate object` you can _infer_ `subject predicate blank-node` which, since blank nodes are existential variables, is like saying "There exists an `x` such that `subject predicate x`.

Comment: This triple :p :name :nickname. :p :name _:n. means: Every person ":p" has a nickname. So I can say that there exists at least one for each person ":p".
But if there's a person, that has no name then you cannot say ":p :name _:n." and so this graph cannot be simple-entailed. Is this true?

Comment: You may have confused existential and universal variables.  A triple `:John :likes :Mary` says that "John likes Mary."  From it we may infer the triple `:John :likes _:x` which says that "John likes something," which is _very_ different from saying that "John likes everything."

Answer (score 1):

Let G1 be:

```
:u rdfs:subClassOf :v .
:u rdfs:domain _:n .
:w rdf:type owl:class .
:w :a :x .
```

and G2 be:

```
:u rdfs:domain _:m .
:w :a :x .
```

G2 contains two triples.

- `:w :a :x .` is also in G1 and is thus entailed.
- `:u rdfs:domain _:m .` is entailed from `:u rdfs:domain _:n .` because of the simple entailement rule :

  ```
  u a x   .
  ---------
  u a _:n .
  ```

The rule means that you can replace any object in a triple by a new blank node (corresponding to an existential variable).